# Get 2nd degree connections details using Linkedin connections API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to use people-API to get second degree data:

Query I am using: `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{id}/connections?modified=new`.

However, I am getting Access to connections denied error. Is there any way to get 2nd connections data?

Answer (score 0):

No. If it was, we wouldn't return an "Access to connections denied error."

Comment: Thanks for response Adam. If the 2nd degree connections has given all access to his profile, then also. Is this feature available in new partner program?